# Using Binomial Distribution to Find the Probability of Two of the Same evnts ocurring

Tags: binomial-distribution

I am doing a Binomial distribution question, in which I have been asked to find the probabability of the same events happening. I know that the probability of the event is 1/3, the number of trials is 20.
I have been asked to find the probability of two students guessing the answers to 20 questions and getting over 10 questions right. 
I have been given the answer as: 0.001414, but I can't figure out how to get to the answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: So far, I have tried to find the probability of getting 9 answers correct and subtracting this from getting 10 answers correct